# R - Forecasting function not working

Tags: r

Hi and thanks in advance.

So I'm trying very hard to get a working forecasting function going in R, but I'm having no luck.

Here's what I need to accomplish:

1) Extract 2 sets of data from a single txt file (one being a value of quantity, and the other being time). The amount of the records must be able to vary (e.g. 4 quantity values in 4 different times, or 5, or 6 etc)

For this I have tried to use a data frame, but the later forecasting function won't accept it for some reason.

2) Put the data into a forecasting function in order to generate new 'forecasted' data (Btw, the method of forecasting that I need to use does not matter at all [I only can't use a mean forecast as it is too simple], but something like a naive or an rwf will work just fine).

3) I want to save the newly produced 'forecasted' data to another txt file for storage.

Here is my code so far:

These lines I used to create and save my sample data (i have currently 18 records):

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

Quantity <- c(5,3,8,4,0,5,2,7,4,2,6,8,4,7,8,9,4,6)
Time <- c("2010/01/01", "2010/07/02", "2010/08/03", "2011/02/04", "2011/11/05", "2011/12/06", "2012/06/07", "2012/08/30", "2013/04/16", "2013/03/18", "2014/02/22", "2014/01/27", "2015/12/15", "2015/09/08", "2016/05/04", "2017/11/07", "2017/09/22", "2017/04/04")
Frame <- data.frame(Time,Quantity)
write.table(Frame,file="....path..../Frame.txt",quote=F)
```

I then used these lines to put that data into (hopefully) a dataframe or any container that could hold both of the above vectors data:

```
Frame <- read.table("....path..../Frame.txt")
```

Out of surety sake, I attempted to plot the data (but I don't need to) just to see if the program has properly read my data (to no avail):

There were 4 plot attempts(unfortunately none succeeded properly):

1-

```
plot.ts(Frame)
```

2-

```
Frame <- read.table("....path..../Frame.txt")
```

3-

```
Frame <- window(start = 2000, end = 2019)
autoplot(Frame) + autolayer(meanf(Frame,h=11),PI=FALSE, series="Means") + autolayer(naive(Frame, h=11),PI=FALSE,series="Naive") + ggtitle("Quantity vs Time") + xlab("Time") + ylab("Quantity") + guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Forecast"))
```

4-

```
plot(Frame, xlab="Time",ylab="Quantity",main="Stock Quantity vs Time",type='l')
```

I have yet to reach the part where I need to send the new 'forecasted' data to a new txt file, so I don't have any attempt code for that.

Any help is appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Start with `Frame$Time <- as.Date(Frame$Time)` immediately after your read.table. `Frame` does not have this as a Date class. I sue ggplot so something like `ggplot(Frame, aes(x=Time, y=Quantity)) +
  geom_line()` gets you a chart

Comment: Thank you. That helped steer me in a better direction. Step by step, I'm getting there :)